# How does モンねぇ effect the sentence?

Tags: grammar, meaning

I've stumbled upon a sentence in a Japanese novel, and I am looking for help from someone who can explain to me the function of "モンねぇ" in this particular sentence.

> 局長が相談に乗ってくれるなら、怖いモンねぇな！

So I believe the sentence would translate to something akin to:

> It's scary if we get advice from the director!

I think モン = もん which could also = もの and I believe it has various different meanings or grammatical functions depending on the context. I also know ねぇ = ない.

However, putting this all together I'm still having a hard time understanding what モンねぇ is doing in the sentence. How does モンねぇ affect the sentence?

Answer (score 7):

Your translation, for some reason, does **not** reflect your grammatical understanding of the expression.  You stated:

> " I also know ねぇ = ない.",

which is correct, but your TL is:

> "***It's scary*** if we get advice from the director!"

Why "It's scary" when ねぇ means ない?　Where did the negative ねぇ go?

> 「モンねぇ」＝「ものない」＝「ものはない」
>
> 「怖{こわ}いモンねぇ」 means "***there is nothing to fear***".

You translated the sentence the opposite way.  My own would be:

> "If we could get advice from the director, we would have nothing to fear/to be afraid of, would we?"